# How to use AucTeX error handing

Tags: auctex

I can't figure out how to use it. Here's what happens if I process a LaTeX file that has multiple errors:

> C-c C-c  (process LaTeX)
>   [errors found]
>   C-c `      (goto first error)
>   fix errors in source window

Now, doing C-c ` again reports "no more errors", but there *are* more errors.
So I save the modified file.  C-c ` at this point returns "no more errors".
 So I do C-c C-c again.
Now Emacs asks if I want to kill the running process.  I can answer 'yes' and it will find the next error.  But I have to do this for every error, killing the running process for each error.  Is that how it's supposed to work?  The docs are silent on how to actually *use* this feature.